# Why does this code throw a read access violation?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management

I need help figuring out why this code is a throwing a read access violation

The Code throws a read-access violation at the 4th value of the array, this started happening when I added the dynamic memory allocation in lines 7 & 8

ProceduralStories.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#include "ProceduralStories.h"

void main()
{
    Object* _objects = NULL;
    _objects = new Object[10];

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Object object = Object
        {
            object.position = glm::vec3 {rand() % 1000 + 1, rand() % 1000 + 1, rand() % 1000 + 1},
            object.mesh = i
        };

        _objects[i] = object;
    }

    Location location1
    {
        location1.position = glm::vec3 {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f},
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        location1.objects[i] = _objects[i]; //Throws a Read Access Violation at the 4th value of the array, so [3]
        std::cout << location1.objects[i].mesh << ", (" << location1.objects[i].position.x << ',' << location1.objects[i].position.y << ',' << location1.objects[i].position.z << ')' << std::endl;
    }
}
```

ProceduralStories.h

```cpp
#include "glm/vec3.hpp"

struct Object
{
    glm::vec3 position;
    int mesh;
};

struct Location
{
    glm::vec3 position;
    Object objects[];
};
```

Comment: location1 didn't allocate space for objects at construction on line 21. As david says in his answer. Also you have a memory leak. _objects is new'd but never deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please don't do this.

Take the time, learn to write a RAII class.

If you write new you must call delete or you'll leak memory in larger projects.

A destructor does this for you when the object falls out of scope. But in this case, you call the default destructor which only calls child destructors and pointers don't clean up themselves.

```cpp
#include<iostream>
struct loc{
    int pos;
    int*obj;
};
void run();
int main(){
   run();
   return 0;
}
void run()
{
    using namespace std;
    loc t{ 42, new int[10]};

    cout<<t.pos<<endl;

    t.obj[0] = 5;
    t.obj[9] = 3;

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cout<<t.obj[i]<<endl;
    }
    delete[] t.obj;
}
```

Edit: I feel responsible for giving a better alternative.

I don't necessarily think this is the best solution, but as I mentioned RAII I'll give you something.

```cpp
#include<iostream>
class loc{
 public:
    int pos;
 private:
    unsigned long size;
    int*obj;
 public:
    loc(): pos{0},size{},obj{nullptr}
    {
    }
    loc(int pos, unsigned long size):pos{pos},size{size}
    {
        obj = new int[size];
    }
    loc(loc&)=delete;
    loc(loc&&)=delete;
    loc operator=(loc&)=delete;
    loc operator=(loc&&)=delete;
    ~loc()
    {
        delete[] obj;
    }
    int&operator[](unsigned long index)
    {
        if(index > size) throw std::out_of_range
        ( "Index "
        + std::to_string(index)
        + " excededs allocated size "
        + std::to_string(size)
        );
        return obj[index];
    }


};
void run()
{
using namespace std;
    loc t{ 42, 10};

    cout<<t.pos<<endl;

    t[0] = 5;
    t[9] = 3;

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cout<<t[i]<<endl;
    }
    // destructor deleate memory for you.
}
```

Please read up on copy move asignment and move asignment constructors and when to use them. As this doesn't and personally, it's out of scope for the problem.

Comment: @user4581301 I don't know if it's proper RAII but I gave it a shot.
Thank you for reminding me of the opportunity. If there's anything to make it better in this context, I welcome edits.

Comment: The update is about right. Three notes: `new` throws exceptions on failure unless specifically asked not to, so you don't have to test for null and throw your own exception. There's no need to clean up trivial things like zeroing an `int` when a constructor throws because the caller isn't going to get an object. You do have to make sure owned and unmanaged resources are released though--right back to RAII; those resources should put themselves back. There is no need for a null check before `delete` because `delete` correctly handles null pointers.

Comment: @user4581301 I took your advice. Thank you for pointing out the unnecessary if's!

Answer (score 2):

You never allocated any space for `objects[]`. So when you try to set `location1.objects[i]` to some value, you're writing to space you haven't allocated.

If you think you did allocate space, show me where and how many entries you allocated space for. You can't do it.